# How can i set a placeholder when redirecting my url with wildfly standalone handlers?

Tags: url-rewriting, wildfly, redirect

I'm trying to redirect my URL with the following settings in the standalone.xml:

```
<server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
            <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/en/" handler="en"/>
                <location name="/de/" handler="de"/>
                <location name="/" handler="de"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
        <servlet-container name="default">
            <jsp-config/>
            <websockets/>
        </servlet-container>
        <handlers>
            <file name="en" path="${jboss.home.dir}/standalone/deployments/en"/>
            <file name="de" path="${jboss.home.dir}/standalone/deployments/de"/>
        </handlers>
```

My handlers point on to the matching angular frontend-projects in the deployments folder of my wildfly-server, where also my EAR-file is deployed.

This works fine except for one case: If i refresh my detail-page, which looks like this: `localhost:8080/en/details/1234` i get an error

> 404 - Page not found
>   I already tried `<location name="/en/details/1234" handler="en"/>` which works, but obviously only for that specific id.

In my understanding this could be solved by adding something like 
`<location name="/en/details/(.*)" handler="en"/>`

My problem is that I can't figure out how to put a placeholder like a regular expression after "details/". Is that even possible? Or is there a better way of handling this redirection/rewriting problem?

I already gave `undertow-handlers.conf` a shot, but it felt like it never really triggered the rewrite rules I implemented there.